Ubuntu mate installation freeze on restart
I am currently trying to install ubuntu mate (jammy jellyfish 22.04.4) on my laptop (acer aspire E5-771G-79X3) which has windows 10 installed on it.
I used rufus to create a bootable usb device with the .iso corresponding file (https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/amd64/).
Everything went just fine until the moment I had to restart my computer. I got that message saying "remove the installation medium then press enter" which I did. And now my computer displays this black screen with three line of text :
[ OK ] Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
[ OK ] Finished System Reboot.
[ OK ] Reached target System Reboot.

It's like a terminal, I can still write text, but nothing is happening, and I don't understand why.
